# JSF2: pass object from list (dataGrid) to action method of commandButton

Tags: jsf-2

How can i pass an object to the action method of an commandButton? I use a datatable which is the basis of a composite component. The composite component should provide the possibility to exchange the buttons which are added to the rows of the datatable. I thought i can realize this with facets, but i have problems passing objects from the datatables list to action methods, neither directly via an EL nor via an property action listener.

View:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:customer="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/customer">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="content">

    <h:form id="customerList">

      <customer:list list="#{customerControllerBean.list}">
        <f:facet name="rowButton">
          <h:commandButton value="#{msg.deleteButtonLabel}"
        action="#{customerControllerBean.delete(customer)}" />

          <h:commandButton value="#{msg.deleteButtonLabel}" action="#{customerControllerBean.deleteCustomer}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{customerControllerBean.customer}" value="#{customer}"/>
          </h:commandButton>

          <h:button outcome="customerdetail.jsf?id=#{customer.id}"
        value="#{msg.editButtonLabel}" />
        </f:facet>
      </customer:list>

    </h:form>

  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

Using the following composite component `customer:list`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="list" />
  <composite:facet name="rowButton" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

  <p:dataTable id="customer" var="customer" value="#{cc.attrs.list}">
    ...
    <p:column>
      <composite:renderFacet name="rowButton" />
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

The backing bean:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class CustomerControllerBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6168621124401208753L;

    List<Customer> allCustomers = null;
    private Customer customer;

    // setters and getters ...

@PostConstruct
public void loadAllCustomers() {
    // load customers
}

public List<Customer> getList() {
    return allCustomers;
}

    public String delete(Customer customer) {
        // delete customer...
        return "deleted";
    }

    public String deleteCustomer() {
        // delete customer...
        return "deleted";
    }
```

Is it not possible to pass objects to methods in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Primefaces you could take advantage of the its datatable features like its properties and events to set your model.

***Using Primefaces' DataTable features***

In your controller you may specify the model and the operations to be performed on it, in this case I used an EJB as example.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CustomerBean 
{
    private Customer model;

    @EJB
    private CustomerService cs;

    public void rowSelected()
    {
        // log or do stuff
    }

    public void delete()
    {
        cs.delete(model);
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

Then you specify the `selectionMode` and the `selection` properties in your datatable, with the `selection` being mapped to your model.

```
<p:dataTable id="dtModel" var="row" value="#{bean.list}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{bean.model}">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="@this" listener="#{bean.rowSelected}" update=":content" />
</p:datatable>
```

In this case I used a listener in the `p:ajax` tag but it is only an example that may be useful if you want to do something with your model once it is selected, but it is not required to set your model. Your model will be set using the bean's setter method.

***Passing row as parameter***

In your controller you specify the method that receives the model as parameter.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CustomerBean 
{
    @EJB
    private CustomerService cs;

    public void delete(Customer candidate)
    {
        cs.delete(candidate);
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

And in your datatable you use the `row` object as specified in `var` property.

```
<p:dataTable id="dtModel" var="row" value="#{bean.list}">
    <p:column headerText="name">
        <h:outputText value="#{row.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="delete">
        <p:commandButton value="delete" actionListener="#{bean.delete(row)}" />
    </p:column> 
</p:datatable>
```

I prefer to use the first example as it allows you to set the model by selecting a row and then performing various operations on it, like delete, edit or view its details. You could enable or disable buttons on your UI by checking if the model is selected or not, etc...

***Hint***

Instead of Composite Components you could use simple Facelets templates to create a simple taglib. They usually work fine, the only downside is that you cannot enforce an interface to the use of these components.

You may also check the PrimeFaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf;jsessionid=fsaf9eivs74n1vopg189hl5f5), which has a lot of useful examples.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your hints. Basically i can pass objects to action methods. I have problems when i add a composite component which carries the datatable and when i add the buttons using a facet. Anyway i tried both examples. I added rowKey as well so the examples compile. The first example does not work, when the setter of the model is called the parameter of the setter is null. The second example works, but only when i add the button directly to the datatable. When i add it through a facet it does not work, the parameter row to the method bean.delete(row) is null as well.

Comment: I see, do you really need to use composite components? I mean, I tried to use them some time ago, spent too much time and found that the simplest scenarios would not work due to the amazing numbers of bugs in the spec and impl. I ended up using simple templates that work as components, creating a simple taglib. Works great but the downside is that you cannot enforce an interface to the components. Regards!

Comment: well.. i am looking for an elegant solution to somehow 'configure' the buttons of e.g. a row in a datatable. one scenario is to have a delete and an edit button, one time is to have a view and select button so i can choose a entity to be set in some other entity... and those buttons invoke different methods on different beans. and i thought facets would be an elegant way to achive this.

Comment: i followed your advice and switched to a template and with ui:define i can insert the buttons and the row object is passed in to the action method. Maybe u want to set the hint from the comment to an answer so i can accept it? :) thanks!